# What is the most efficient way to do this (jquery snippet)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

```
$("#content").scroll(function(e){
    var distance_from_top = $("#content").scrollTop();
    var theinverse = -1 * distance_from_top;
    var theinverse2 = theinverse + "px";
    $("#topheader").css( "marginTop", theinverse2);
});
```

What's the most efficient way to do the above? Basically make #topheader top margin equal to the negative distance scrolled from the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

caching caching caching.

```
content = $("#content");
topheader = document.getElementById("topheader");
content.scroll(function() {
    topheader.style.marginTop  = -content.scrollTop() + "px";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Efficient or short because you could simply do this for shortness.

```
$("#content").scroll(function(e){
    $("#topheader").css( "marginTop", -$("#content").scrollTop() + "px");
});
```

When probably need more context (source of the web page) if you want efficiency.